# New Computer bought will information be deleted?

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization, backup

I bought a new computer recently and have not plugged my iphone into it yet. I had my phone synced with my old computer which crashed and cannot retrieve any information off of it including my music. So if I plug my iPhone into my new computer will everything be deleted or since I have iCloud will everything be saved? I want to know this information before I would plug into my new computer.

Answer (score 1):

On your iPhone go to *Settings* > *iCloud* > *Storage and Backup* and turn on *iCloud Backup*

It will save your configurations and pictures on iCloud. This is the same you do when you sync your iPhone with iTunes. In this way you can restore your data from iCloud.

Once you have done the first backup you can attach the iPhone to your computer without loosing data.

Answer (score 0):

On your new computer, you can also open iTunes, visit the iTunes Store and click the *Purchased* link in the upper right menu (depending on your country, this might be in a different language. You can visit the US store first, spot the menu entry there, and return to your store to find your version of it). This link will bring you to a page where you can re-download all the apps, books, and songs you purchased in iTunes.

But this will only work for iTunes purchased things.